# Error when applying OpenCV SURF to HSV color space in python

Tags: opencv, image-processing, surf

I am implementening [SURF](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html) to HSV image, but It is not working.
And when I am doing same to RGB image, It works fine.

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#loaading image
rgb_img_arr= np.array(Image.open("myImage.jpg"))
hsv_image_arr=matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv(rgb_img_arr)

surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()

#it works fine
keypoints, descriptors = surf.detectAndCompute(rgb_img_arr, None)
rgb_img = cv2.drawKeypoints(rgb_img_arr, keypoints, None)
plt.imshow(rgb_img )

#But it doent work
keypoints, descriptors = surf.detectAndCompute(hsv_image_arr, None)
hsv_img = cv2.drawKeypoints(hsv_image_arr, keypoints, None)
plt.imshow(hsv_img )
```

Error I am getting is -

> C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\xfeatures2d\src\surf.cpp:892: error: (-215) !_img.empty() && ((imgtype) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) == 0 && (imgcn == 1 || imgcn == 3 || imgcn == 4) in function cv::xfeatures2d::SURF_Impl::detectAndCompute

Please tell me how can i fix this
 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`detectAndCompute` expects a CV_8U image. `(imgtype) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) == 0` is a bit cryptic, but if you follow the error to the source you can see that there: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/2231018c839d728811a39556ec83741bf9a27614/modules/xfeatures2d/src/surf.cpp#L892

The HSV conversion `matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv` is returning a float image instead.

Either you convert your float image back to an unsigned one. Or you can directly use the OpenCV color conversion, which will return an 8U image by default:

```
hsv_image_array = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
```

Comment: ohh...great catch.
Thanks for your time.